# gregorio - Is there a way to increase spacing between staffs?

Tags: gregorio

Using lualatex in TeXLive 2016:

Let's say I wanted to add more whitespace between each staff.  How would that work?

Would such a parameter be defined in the .gabc or in the .tex file?

**Edit:**

Here's a screenshot of what I'd be looking for.

[image: More Whitespace?]

Comment: Please show us a short, compilable code we can play with. Can you mark in a screenshot where you want more whitespace?

Comment: Please add the compilable code you created the screenshot too.  That makes it easier to help you, because one can copy the code and test it on the own computer and play with it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set bigger `\baselineskip`. I played with the example file `main-lualatex.tex` and I replaced the line 41 from

```
\gregorioscore[a]{PopulusSion}
```

to

```
{\baselineskip=70pt \gregorioscore[a]{PopulusSion}}
```

and the desired effect appeared.

Comment: The official interface is `\grechangedim{baselineskip}{<glue>}{scalable}` (where `scalable` could also be `fixed`: in the `scalable` case the `<glue>` will be scaled depending on the main font size). This won't influence the baseline skip of normal text.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back here.  \baselineskip did the trick. Thanks!